# What's a good open source solution that supports push e-mail?

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, imap

Currently using Exim4 + courier-imaps + spamassassin but would like to get push e-mail on my iPhone and Android devices!

Answer (score 1):

I am using dovecot, which allows me to fetch mail with my android. If your email client supports IMAP Idle you will get new mail immediately.

Found this: http://dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2010-April/048171.html

Comment: Thanks -- the problem is there aren't any mail clients for mobile devices that support IMAP idle.  Once the phone goes to sleep the TCP/IP connections die.

Comment: With dovecot there seems to be a possible solution to get real push support: http://www.cklog.net/push-email-with-dovecot-mail-server/